# What is Amy's timeline in the series 6 finale?

Tags: doctor-who

I was just watching the series 6 finale of Doctor Who and I am wondering, which Amy it was, who appeared in the end.

> River Song asks, where she is in time. She answers that the Doctor has just died. But she was not the Amy who joined the picnic at lake Silencio. So what happened to her? She was dropped off by the Doctor in the end of ep. 11. But then? How (and when) did she experience the death of the Doctor?

What is Amy's timeline through the series 6 finale? How did she come to the picnic at the lake?

Comment: I'm pretty sure she was the Amy at the lake.

Comment: Can't be the Amy from the lake. The wine-drinking Amy knows who River Song is, the lake-Amy doesn't. And lake-Amy saw the Doctor die, but it was a Doctor from her future, the Doctor from her present is still alive.

Answer (score 4):

This does seem like an inconsistency. It can't be the Amy who was just at the lake, as she experiences the whole of Series 6 alongside the Doctor directly afterwards.

I suppose it could be during the hiatus between the two halves of the season, when the Doctor is busy looking for baby Melody, but that seems unlikely given Amy's state of mind in this scene, and the nature of her interaction with River.

The most likely explanation would seem to be that this occurs soon after the Doctor drops Amy and Rory off at their new house after "The God Complex" - presumably Amy has had some time to reflect on events at this point, and has realised that "now" the Doctor is dead from her point of view.

Comment: But she says that the Doctor just died. And she remembers, what had happened in the all-history-at-the-same-time-universe.

Comment: @TillB With the history occuring all at the same time sequence Amy should theoretically have remembered that alternate non-time her entire life, since it all happened at the same time anyway.

Comment: @Xantec That would mean that she remembered it before she met the Doctor. And everybody else remembers it. But maybe only "complicated space-time-events" remember it.

Comment: I just re-watched the episode.  Her line wasn't "the Doctor just died".  Rather she said "the Doctor's dead".  So, it could have been any amount of time after the Doctor died.  And realizing that River was coming to visit could easily bring back all the bad memories and sadness flooding back again.

Answer (score 1):

It is the Amy that has gone through the events of Season 6 as she mentions the Doctor saying that he just told River his name in "Wedding of River Song".

She also says something like "I'm his Mother in law" at the end of Wedding of River Song.

So I have fully belief that the Amy we see is the one that not only saw what happened at the lake, but the Amy that went through all the events we see in Season 6.